# Capistrano Deploy, access ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano3

Okay,

I'm sorry if the title is not descriptive enough, but allow me to explain what I want to achieve:

- I have a Rails 3 application
- During my deploy, it needs to call `pg_dump` with the correct parameters to restore a backup
- The task needs to be ran after the deploy is done but before the migrations.

The problem I have however, is that for this task, I would like to access Rails specific code, which is not working as Capistrano keeps throwing a lot of errors at me like gems not available or module not defined.

This is my Rake task:

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :rm do
    desc 'Backup the database'
    task :backup do

      # Generates the command to invoke the Rails runner
      # Used by the cfg method to execute the ActiveRecord configuration in the rails config.
      def runner
        dir = "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current"
        bundler = "#{SSHKit.config.command_map.prefix[:bundle].first} bundle exec"
        env = fetch(:rails_env)
        "cd #{dir}; #{bundler} rails r -e #{env}"
      end

      def cfg(name)
        env = fetch(:rails_env)
        command = "\"puts ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['#{env}']['#{name}']\""
        "#{runner} #{command}"
      end

      on roles(:db) do
        timestamp = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        backups = File.expand_path(File.join(fetch(:deploy_to), '..', 'backups'))
        execute :mkdir, '-p', backups
        dump = "PGPASSWORD=`#{cfg('password')}` pg_dump -h `#{cfg'host')}` -U `#{cfg('username')}` `#{cfg('database')}`"
        fn = "#{timestamp}_#{fetch(:stage)}.sql.gz"
        path = File.join(backups, fn)
        execute "#{dump} | gzip > #{path}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In it's current form, it simply generates a string with the `runner` method and dumps that inside the `cfg` method.

I tried rewriting the `runner` method, but for some reason I keep getting the `runner --help` output from the remote server, but the command being generated in the output is correct, and works locally just fine.

We are using `Ruby 2.2.2` and RVM on the remote server.
Is it even possible to do what we are trying to construct together?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing a rake task inside your Rails app and invoking that from your Capistrano task. This is how the [Capistrano rails tasks work](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake#L16).

```
within release_path do
  with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
    execute :rake, "db:migrate"
  end
end
```

Comment: will give this a spin